# Is there any way to estimate the covariance matrix of a nonlinear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, nonlinear-system, covariance

Suppose $\mathbf{x}=f(\mathbf{y})$ where vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ $\in R^N$, and the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{y}$ is given as $\sigma_y$. How do we estimate the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: suppose vector y is also unknown, but the mean of y is known.